# AWS EC2 terminal session terminated with "Plugin with name Standard_Stream not found"

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I was streaming Kafka on AWS EC2 CentOS 7. My Session Manager Idle Timeout is set to 60min. And yet, after running for much less than that, the terminal got frozen, saying `My session has been terminated`. Of course, the Kafka streaming for disrupted as well.

When I tried to restart a new session with a new terminal, I got this error popup

```
Your session has been terminated for the following reasons: Plugin with name Standard_Stream not found. Step name: Standard_Stream
```

and I am still unable to restart a terminal.

What does this error mean and how to resolve it? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SSM agent can report this error in two situations.

1. Total number of open files across the system has reached system wide limit of max open files.
2. System has reached limit for inotify sub system in the kernel

### Increase the max open files:

```
$ sudo sysctl -w fs.file-max=100000
```

To set it permanent, append below line to /etc/sysctl.conf

```
$ fs.file-max = 100000
```

### Checking the limits on inotify subsystem:

```
$ sudo cat /proc/sys/fs/inotify/max_user_instances:
```

> This specifies an upper limit on the number of inotify instances that can be created per real user ID. Default is 128

```
$ sudo cat /proc/sys/fs/inotify/max_user_watches:
```

> This specifies an upper limit on the number of watches that can be created per real user ID. Default is 8192

To check the inotify resource consumption per process, you can run below command.

```
$ sudo find /proc/*/fd -lname anon_inode:inotify | cut -d/ -f3 | xargs -I '{}' -- ps --no-headers -o '%p %U %c' -p '{}' | uniq -c | sort -nr
```

Test with tail -f to see if there is still room for new inotify watchers. Run this as root user and look for any message similar to "tail: inotify cannot be used, reverting to polling: Too many open files"

```
$ sudo su -

$ tail -f /var/log/syslog
```

If you get that error, it is then that the system has reached one of above limits for inotify subsystem. Increase the limits or reboot to clear. Test it again using tail -f to see if new watchers are being created after the changes.

```
$ sudo sysctl fs.inotify.max_user_watches=16384

$ sudo sysctl fs.inotify.max_user_instances=256
```

To make this change persistent across reboot.

```
$ echo "fs.inotify.max_user_watches = 16384” >> /etc/sysctl.d/20-fs-inotify.conf

$ echo "fs.inotify.max_user_instances = 256” >> /etc/sysctl.d/20-fs-inotify.conf
```

Answer (score 9):

- So far you need to access the EC2 using SSH with key-pem to debug
  (ask your admin)

Running `tail -f` got issue

```
tail: inotify resources exhausted
tail: inotify cannot be used, reverting to polling
```

- Restart ssm-agent service also got issue `No space left on device`
  but it's not about disk space

  [root@env-test ec2-user]# systemctl restart amazon-ssm-agent.service
  Error: No space left on device

  [root@env-test ec2-user]# df -h |grep dev
  devtmpfs         32G     0   32G   0% /dev
  tmpfs            32G     0   32G   0% /dev/shm
  /dev/nvme0n1p1  100G   82G   18G  83% /
- So the error itself means that system is getting low on inotify
  watches, that enable programs to monitor file/dirs changes. To see
  the currently set limit (including output on my machine)

  $ cat /proc/sys/fs/inotify/max_user_watches

  8192

Check which processes using inotify to improve your apps or increase `max_user_watches`

```
for foo in /proc/*/fd/*; do readlink -f $foo; done | grep inotify | sort | uniq -c | sort -nr
5 /proc/1/fd/anon_inode:inotify
2 /proc/7126/fd/anon_inode:inotify
2 /proc/5130/fd/anon_inode:inotify
1 /proc/4497/fd/anon_inode:inotify
1 /proc/4437/fd/anon_inode:inotify
1 /proc/4151/fd/anon_inode:inotify
1 /proc/4147/fd/anon_inode:inotify
1 /proc/4028/fd/anon_inode:inotify
1 /proc/3913/fd/anon_inode:inotify
1 /proc/3841/fd/anon_inode:inotify
1 /proc/31146/fd/anon_inode:inotify
1 /proc/2829/fd/anon_inode:inotify
1 /proc/21259/fd/anon_inode:inotify
1 /proc/1934/fd/anon_inode:notify
```

- Notice that the above inotify list include PID of ssm-agent
  processes, it explains why we got issue with SSM when
  `max_user_watches` reached limit

ps -ef | grep ssm-ag

```
root      3841     1  0 00:02 ?        00:00:05 /usr/bin/amazon-ssm-agent
root      4497  3841  0 00:02 ?        00:00:33 /usr/bin/ssm-agent-worker
```

- Final Solution: Permanent solution (preserved across restarts)

`echo "fs.inotify.max_user_watches=1048576" >> /etc/sysctl.conf sysctl -p`

- Verify:

  `$ aws ssm start-session --target i-123abc456efd789xx --region ap-northeast-2`

Starting session with SessionId: userdev-03ccb1a04a6345bf5

sh-4.2$

- This issue comes from EC2 instance not about SSM agent Go to [link](https://dev.to/vumdao/understand-amazon-ssm-agent-in-2-minutes-1363) to
  undestanding SSM agent.

optional [link](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/systems-manager/latest/userguide/session-manager-working-with-install-plugin.html)

Comment: Thanks. I contacted AWS and they need to reconfigure volume size and OS, similarly to what you suggested here.

Comment: A nice cli exists to view the resources associated with notify, I'm unaffiliated.  https://github.com/mikesart/inotify-info.git

Answer (score 3):

In my case, extend the disk space works!
(syslog full of my case)

Answer (score 2):

Just restarting the ec2 instance solved the issue `Your session has been terminated for the following reasons: Plugin with name Standard_Stream not found. Step name: Standard_Stream`

Answer (score 1):

In my case too extending the disk space worked as my /var/logs was huge.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

In my case rebooting the machine worked. Seems a process was stuck, and it was consuming all of my machine's resources which wouldn't allow the ssm agent to work correctly. Your session has been terminated for the following reasons: Plugin with name Standard_Stream not found. Step name: Standard_Stream.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).