# AWS EC2 instance connection error in AWS console(Plugin with name Standard_Stream not found. Step name: Standard_Stream)

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

```
Plugin with name Standard_Stream not found. Step name: Standard_Stream
```

I'm using AWS EC2 connection as AWS console. But I got mentioned error.

What does this error mean and how to resolve it? Thanks.

Comment: Do you receive the same error if you try connecting with a different browser (eg Chrome, Firefox, Safari)?

Comment: @JohnRotenstein Yes. I got the same error in Chrome, Firefox and Safari. Only a specific ec2 instance is not connected, and the rest of the instances are connected well.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [AWS EC2 terminal session terminated with "Plugin with name Standard\_Stream not found"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69337154/aws-ec2-terminal-session-terminated-with-plugin-with-name-standard-stream-not-f)